# IF 25% match or more, sum up values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to use a formula to get excel to look at values and determine if they have atleast a 25% match then to add their values. Kind of like a vlookup and IF function combined but I am not sure how to do the 25% part. The reason I ask this is because I have a data set with Company names that are the same company but they are all typed in differently so excel recognizes them as separate companies. For example:

```
Company:               Value
XYZ Incorperated       25
XYZ Company            40
XYZ                    12
ABC INC.               39
ABC inc.               10
ABC COMPANY            15
```

I need it to realize that all the companies with "XYZ" are the same and to add all their values. Same goes for "ABC". Again, I am not entirely sure it is possible but I haven't been able to find a way to get excel to sum it up for me.

*Side note* I could do it manually but the problem is that the data set is always changing so I need a formula that can recognize the similarities in each cell.

Comment: You may consider [downloading a fuzzy lookup add-in](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011) from Microsoft.  Some documentation can be found [here](http://www.excel-bytes.com/fuzzy-lookup-in-excel/).

Comment: Take a look at the Fuzzy Lookup Addin from Microsoft: [http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011][1]


  [1]: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011 Does that do what you want?

Comment: this looks like it would work. I will have to look into it. Thanks for the help guys, I will let you know if this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Sumproduct.  I am assuming that all of your Column A will start with the company name.  (I.e. there won't be 'Company XYZ', only 'XYZ [...]'.  If this isn't always going to be the case, let me know.

Does this work? I assumed Company is Col. A, Value is Col. B - going to row 7.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT($A$2:$A$7,LEN(E2))=E2),--($B$2:$B$7>=25),$B$2:$B$7)`

So, if a cell has "XYZ" as company, and the "Value" for that row is 25 or greater, it'll add together.  The XYZ cell equates to 65, and you can see the ABC correctly calculates 39.

[image]

edit: Here's a screenshot, using named ranges to maybe make it easier to see what goes where in the formula:

[image]

Comment: Understood - I'll see if I can figure something else out (without getting into VB) to help.

Comment: This works except i took out the greater than 25 cause I need it to add all values that are related to that company. While it is one step closer, my biggest problem is that i have to go through the list and type out what companies exist in that data set (every time new data comes in, it wont be the same companies as the set before)

Comment: @THATnewbie - you can simplify that.  When you get a new dataset, you can copy all your companies, paste them somewhere else, then run "Remove Duplicates' (under 'Data' tab) to remove any duplicates.  That'll leave you with unique companies.  Then, you can run the formula.  Then, you can further refine your companies and merge and sum. (I.e. "XYZ Inc." + "XYZ Company" will total ____)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the `--` do in the function?

Comment: @THATnewbie - "By using the double negative -- (double unary, for you technical types) we are able to coerce the TRUE/FALSE into the numeric values one and zero..." [here's a page](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function) that details it a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes try SUMPRODUCT it is great. Very simply, it look through column B which is the company names to match the left three characters in the name to what ever you type in cell E3 and sums the values in the value column.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(B4:B9,3)=E3)*1,C4:C9)
```

Comment: The sumproduct does work for the above example, however, i am not sure that if future data comes in, that the first 3 letters will all always be the same.

Comment: So another option is to use `=SUMIF(B3:B8,E3,C3:C8)` put your search criteria in cell `E3` and it needs to look like `*XYZ*`. The asterisks are the wildcard markers. The B column is the search column and the C column is the return value.